# how to download csv file getting in api

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

hi I am getting a csv file in a api and getting in this function like :

```
def download_file(account_id, user_id, payload):
    print(file_name)
    file_path = '/tmp/test.csv'
    payload
    print(payload)
```

I want to download this file in this path . in payload I am getting this csv file . and want to store at this path  **file_path = '/tmp/test.csv'**

Answer (score -1):

you can open a writable file handle with the `open` function

```
def download_file(account_id, user_id, payload):
    file_path = '/tmp/test.csv'
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(payload)
```